# assetic exception when using assetic:dump and compass with symfony2

Tags: symfony, compass-sass, assetic

I have a few scss files imported into a larger one using scss's @import statement. When trying to dump the assets I get the following exception:

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump --force --verbose
Dumping all dev assets.
Debug mode is on.
[file+] sf_project/app/../web/js/f389f05.js
        sf_project/src/Theaterjobs/MainBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js
[file+] sf_project/app/../web/js/f389f05_jquery-1.6.3.min_1.js
        sf_project/src/Theaterjobs/MainBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js
[file+] sf_project/app/../web/css/e9b81fe.css
        sf_project/src/Theaterjobs/MainBundle/Resources/assets/css/_base.scss
        sf_project/src/Theaterjobs/MainBundle/Resources/assets/css/_structure.scss
        sf_project/src/Theaterjobs/MainBundle/Resources/assets/css/theaterjobs.scss

  [RuntimeException]  

Exception trace:
 () at sf_project/vendor/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/CompassFilter.php:278
 Assetic\Filter\CompassFilter->filterLoad() at sf_project/vendor/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/FilterCollection.php:62
 Assetic\Filter\FilterCollection->filterLoad() at sf_project/vendor/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/BaseAsset.php:83
 Assetic\Asset\BaseAsset->doLoad() at sf_project/vendor/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/FileAsset.php:57
 Assetic\Asset\FileAsset->load() at sf_project/vendor/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/BaseAsset.php:92
 Assetic\Asset\BaseAsset->dump() at sf_project/vendor/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/AssetCollection.php:97
 Assetic\Asset\AssetCollection->dump() at sf_project/vendor/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle/Command/DumpCommand.php:206
 Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Command\DumpCommand->doDump() at sf_project/vendor/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle/Command/DumpCommand.php:163
 Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Command\DumpCommand->dumpAsset() at sf_project/vendor/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle/Command/DumpCommand.php:62
 Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Command\DumpCommand->execute() at sf_project/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:214
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at sf_project/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:194
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at sf_project/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:75
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at sf_project/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:118
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at sf_project/app/console:16
```

paths shortened for readability :)

our config.yml looks like this

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:
          bin: /usr/local/bin/sass
        compass:
          bin: /usr/local/bin/compass
        yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar"
```

I'm including the stylesheets using

```
{% stylesheets filter="compass,cssrewrite" '@TheaterjobsMainBundle/Resources/assets/css/*' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I have no idea whats going on. I'll dump you any output that might help solve this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out it was the fact that I was including the stylesheets with `'@TheaterjobsMainBundle/Resources/assets/css/*'` (with the wildcard in the path) instead of linking directly to the main scss file that imports all the scss partials using @import.

so sf was trying to compile the partials as well and failed because of unset variables.

not clearing the cache wasn't that helpful, either :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that exception is thrown when the Compass process cannot be executed or does not finish correctly. Are you sure your compass path is correct? I think that's the default you have there but depending on your system it could be different. For instance on Ubuntu Server 11.04 my SCSS path is:

`sass: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/sass`

So make sure compass actually resides in `/usr/local/bin/compass` and not somewhere else.